# how to populate data from a clickable div to a textbox?

Tags: php, jquery, html, clickable

I am trying to populate data from a click-able div container to a text box.
All the below code is present in same file "schedule.php".

The jQuery function is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#listItem1").click(function(){
  var selectedAddress = $("#listItem1").attr("value");
  $.post("schedule.php",selectedAddress,function(selectedAddress){
    addressSelect($("#listItem1").attr("value"));
  });

 });
});
```

The php code is present in the same file:

```
<?php 
  function addressSelect($selectedAddress) {
$selectedAddress=$_POST['$selectedAddress'];    
//echo $selectedAddress;
    if(isset($selectedAddress)) list($fromName, $fromAddress, $fromCity,     $fromState, $fCountry, $fromZip, $fromPhone) = explode("$$$", $selectedAddress);
  }
?>
```

I am not able to populate it. I tried to using $.ajax also... but not helping.. what should I do to populate the textboxes at all.

The HTML is like this:

```
<table CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1 border=0 width=200>
    <tr><td colspan=4 height=10></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td width=7></td>
      <td WIDTH=180 height=35><b>Name</b><font size="-1" color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
      <td colspan=2 WIDTH=220>
        <input NAME="fromName" TYPE="text" id="fromName" placeholder="Sender's Name" style="width:150px;" value="<?php echo $fromName;?>" MAXLENGTH="35" autofocus onBlur="ValidateName(fromName)">
        <span class="error">  <?php echo $fromNameErr;?></span>
      </td>
    </tr>    

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td height=35><b>Address</b><font size="-1" color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
      <td>
      <TEXTAREA NAME="fromAddress" COLS=30 ROWS=3 id="fromAddress" placeholder="Sender's Address" style="width:200px; height:130px; font-size:13px; font-family:Arial,sans-serif" onBlur="ValidateAddress(fromAddress)"></TEXTAREA>
      <span class="error">  <?php echo $fromAddressErr;?></span>
      </td>      
      <td rowspan=3 align="center"></td>     
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td height=35><b>Landmark</td>
      <td>
      <input NAME="fromLandmark" TYPE="text" id="fromLandmark" placeholder="optional" style="width:150px" value="<?php echo $fromLandmark;?>" MAXLENGTH=45>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td height=35><b>City</b><font size="-1" color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
      <td>
      <input NAME="fromCity" TYPE="text" id="fromCity" placeholder="Source City" style="width:150px" value="<?php echo $fromCity;?>" MAXLENGTH=35>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td height=35><b>State</b><font size="-1" color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
      <td colspan=2>
      <input NAME="fromState" TYPE="text" id="fromState" placeholder="State of Source City" style="width:150px" value="<?php echo $fromState;?>" MAXLENGTH=25>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td height=35><b>Zip</b><font size="-1" color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
      <td colspan=2>
      <input NAME="fromZip" TYPE="text" id="fromZip" placeholder="Pin Code" style="width:90px" value="<?php echo $fromZip;?>" MAXLENGTH=15 onBlur="ValidateZip(fromZip)">
      <span class="error">  <?php echo $fromZipErr;?></span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td height=35><b>Country</b></td>
      <td colspan=2>
      <select NAME="fromCountry" id="fromCountry" disabled="disabled">
      <?php populate_country();?>
      </select></div></td>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td height=35><b>Phone</b><font size="-1" color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
      <td colspan=2>
      <input NAME="fromPhone" TYPE="text" id="fromPhone" placeholder="Sender's Phone no." style="width:150px" value="<?php echo $fromPhone;?>" MAXLENGTH=15 onBlur="ValidatePhone(fromPhone)">
      <span class="error">  <?php echo $fromPhoneErr;?></span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan=4 height=10></td></tr>
  </table>
        <?php /*?><td style="border-right:1px solid #b2b2b2; font-size:1px; background-color: #fafafa">&nbsp;</td><?php */?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=6 height=6></td>
        <?php /*?><td height=6 style="border-bottom:1px solid #b2b2b2; font-size:1px; background-color: #fafafa">&nbsp;</td><?php */?>
        <td width=6 height=6></td>
    </tr>
  </table><!-- End of From Address container table-->
```

Comment: please provide your html

Comment: If #listItem1 is a div then you will not have attribute value. instead use $("#listItem1").html()

Comment: @MazIqbal , listItem1 is inside a div. SO, the div shows the entire address as a block. Upon clicking it, the values inside the address should be parsed and populated into Name, Address, city, etc textboxes...

Answer (score 1):

The code provided by @user2298875 has a little mistake. Change

```
    content = $("#" + divId).innerHTML;
    $("#" + textBoxId).value = content;
```

to

```
$("#" + textBoxId).val($("#" + divId).html());
```

Comment: Try and console log div's content. What is it that you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to copy the data on the browser and not on the server. You can use the following JQuery code to get it done:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function copyData(divId, textBoxId) { 
        content = $("#" + divId).html();
        $("#" + textBoxId).val(content); 
    }
</script> 
<body>
    <div id="my-div" onclick="copyData('my-div', 'my-text-box');">
        This the data to be copied.
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="my-text-box" name="myTextBox"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the content is not supposed to be copied in a single textbox, it has to be parsed and populated in different textboxes in a same form. That is why i have written the php code.

Comment: I agree with @user2298875, why would you need a server-side script for something as simple as this? Just use JQuery or JavaScript (JQuery preferred) and get it done. KISS principle, remember?

Comment: @BasitSaeed I tried the solution given above, but its not working.... the variable content is undefined. I tried to print it by alert(content) and its showing me "undefined".

Comment: See my posted answer.

Comment: @ManoharSwami Was a bit over-confident about my code. have corrected it now, as mentioned by Basit also. Let me know what kind of parsing you want to do. Will suggest you suitable code to get your work done.

Comment: Finally got it using     


$.trim(content.split('$$$')[0]);